# Session invalidation caused by SessionFixationProtectionStrategy

Tags: grails, spring-security, grails-2.0

- Grails 2.3.2
- Spring Security 2.0RC

Started getting lots of "session already invalidated" exceptions in our Grails application since the migration to 2.3.x and new version of spring security plugin.
 
Issue seems to be related to logic in SessionFixationProtectionStrategy. When user posts 2 simultaneous request to the server (in 2 browser tabs):

- "1"-login
- "2"-view custom page

, the following scenario is happening:

1. Both requests are using the same SID -> "A".
2. Login request - "1" upon successful authentication invalidates session A and creates session B. Personal page is displayed to the logged in user.
3. Custom page request - "2" tries to access the session A during the page rendering and encounters session invalidated exception. A new session gets created for this request with SID -> "C", and browser cookies get over written.
4. Both opened tabs will be using SID -> "C", for further requests, hence will be asked  to login again.

```
A1  A2
|   | 
B1  A2 - crashes
|   |   
B1  |
|   C2 - recreated for the user
|
C2
```

The above behavior doesn't seems right, therefore my question is how to handle this properly.

Comment: Unfortunately this seems as a correct behaviour to me... would be nice if this has a solution. +1

Comment: Actually reading the question again the step C3 should not create a new session! It should redirect user to login page... that request would either be with the new session id or it should not create a new session neither.

Comment: Thanks Pavel, just found that redirect to an error page goes after the A2 - crash step. At that point our grails Filters are triggered, those are accessing the session object. As per the grails behaviour that will always create a new session if it doesn't exist. Hence, the solution would be to exclude error page/action from filters. Trying this solution in the meantime...

Answer (score 0):

You can just turn off the Session Fixation Protection.

In java:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
...
 @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        ...
        http.sessionManagement().sessionFixation().none();
    }
...
}
```

In XML (Spring-Security.xml):

```
<http>      
    <session-management session-fixation-protection="none"/>
</http>
```